# aspnetcore is skipping authentication middle ware

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently using 3 middleware in my .netcore api application.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMultiTenancy();
app.UseMvc();
```

From my understanding each middleware is run based on the sequence they are added to the pipeline.

For some reasons, the UseMultiTenancy is run before UseAuthentication.
Note, all my API controllers are marked with authorize attributes.

I would expect the authentication middleware to check whether the user has been authentication and then call the UseMultiTenancy .

Is this correct understanding? If not, is there a way to run UseMultiTenancy after authentication?

Comment: No, Authorization isn't checked until you reach the controller.

Comment: Do you have any granular authorization or do you only require users to be authenticated?

Comment: I just want to access user's claims. From the claim, I want to obtain the subjectId. It looks like that the only way to access claims is when the user has been authenticated.

Comment: I have another service class called ITenantService. I plan to set the userId that i obtained from token in this service class along with some custom http header information. This service is used inside my dbcontext

Comment: My dbcontext then reads the values inside service class and passes them to  sp_set_session_context for Row level security

Comment: UseAuthentication will load the claims if you configured a default scheme. What it won't do is reject anonymous users, that's Authorization. You can add a simple middleware after UseAuthentication that challenges anonymous users.